# PowerShell script unable to upload zip file to storage account from Windows virtual machine

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage

In a Windows Server 2019 Datacenter virtual machine I want to upload a file
(**C:\Data\Archive\20240312_Log.zip**) to storage account. However, I get the following error:

```
Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation.).
CategoryInfo InvalidOperation: (Method: PUT, Reques…-Length: 6159687
}:HttpRequestMessage) [Invoke-RestMethod], HttpResponseException
FullyQualifiedErrorId: WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
StackTrace: at SendToStorageAccount, <No file>: line 18
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
The File 20240312_Log.zip FAILED to upload
```

In the 'logs' container, I have created the following SAS token:

[image: SAS Token]

The network restriction on the Storage Account is: **Enabled from all networks**

I have created a different SAS Token with my laptop IP whitelisted, and I am able to upload the zip file with the following script. But it fails to upload from the vm:

```
function SendToStorageAccount {
    param (
        [string] $zipFileName
    )
    $myDevSas = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('myDevSas','Machine')
    #The target URL wit SAS Token
    $uri = "https://mystdev.blob.core.windows.net/logs/$($zipFileName)?$($myDevSas)"

    #Define required Headers
    $headers = @{
        'x-ms-blob-type' = 'BlockBlob'
    }
    #Upload File...
    $apiCall
    try {
        $apiCall = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -Headers $headers -InFile $zipFileName    
        Write-Output $apiCall
        Write-Output "The File $($zipFileName) uploaded successfully"
        Remove-Item $zipFileName
    }
    catch {
        "Message: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        "CategoryInfo $($_.CategoryInfo)"
        "FullyQualifiedErrorId: $($_.FullyQualifiedErrorId)"
        "StackTrace: $(($_.ScriptStackTrace -replace '^'))"
        Write-Output $apiCall
        Write-Output "The File $($zipFileName) FAILED to upload"
    }
}


$fileName = "20240312_Log.zip"
SendToStorageAccount $fileName
```

TIA!

Comment: where is `$myDevSas` defined? You have the `GetEnvironmentVariable` commented.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, my typo, the code ran w/o the comment.

Comment: @scv If you are storage account networking is enabled for all networks, you don't need to specify allowed ip address.

Comment: Does `[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('myDevSas','Machine')` return "sv=your_key_here" or just the key? Also for your `-InFile`, can you confirm the zip file is in the script root folder? Otherwise you'll need to provide a full path.

Comment: @Venkatesan, thanks for the tip. I learned something today.

Comment: @MikeAnthony, the GetEnvironmentVariable returns 'sp=raw...." (just the key). The key was only good for a day, so another key was generated. And this time it works. Not sure if it was my typo somewhere or what got it to work.  

Thank you all for your help, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

> Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 403  (This request is not authorized to perform this operation.).

The above error occurs when you don't have enough permission or you're passing the wrong SAS token to access the storage account.

> The network restriction on the Storage Account is: **Enabled from all networks**

If your storage account networking is enabled from all networks, then you don't need to pass the VM IP address in your SAS token.

In my environment, I created a virtual machine and created a SAS token without passing the IP address. The same script executed successfully.

**Script:**

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('myDevSas', 'sp=racwl&st=2024-03-13T05:53:48Z&se=2024-03-13T13:53:48Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=xxxx', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)

function SendToStorageAccount {
    param (
        [string] $zipFileName
    )
    $myDevSas = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('myDevSas','Machine')
    #The target URL with SAS Token
    $uri = "https://venkat789.blob.core.windows.net/logs/$($zipFileName)?$($myDevSas)"

    #Define required Headers
    $headers = @{
        'x-ms-blob-type' = 'BlockBlob'
    }
    #Upload File...
    $apiCall
    try {
        $apiCall = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -Headers $headers -InFile $zipFileName    
        Write-Output $apiCall
        Write-Output "The file $($zipFileName) uploaded successfully"
        Remove-Item $zipFileName
    }
    catch {
        "Message: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        "CategoryInfo $($_.CategoryInfo)"
        "FullyQualifiedErrorId: $($_.FullyQualifiedErrorId)"
        "StackTrace: $(($_.ScriptStackTrace -replace '^'))"
        Write-Output $apiCall
        Write-Output "The file $($zipFileName) FAILED to upload"
    }
}


$fileName = "antarctica-latest-free.zip"
SendToStorageAccount $fileName
```

**Output:**

```
The file antarctica-latest-free.zip uploaded successfully
```

[image]